# Writing the data into specific cell of an excel using OpenXML writer

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, openxml-sdk

I have a common requirement where i have an excel template with 3 predefined sheets and i have to enter the values into these sheets dynamically, i.e., by fetching the values from the database.

I have read almost all the articles on StackOverFlow about OpenXMLWriter but none helped me in achieving my requirement.

The template cannot be altered but only the values have to be filled in to specific cells, which by the way have column heading. I have to use SAX approach as data retrieved from DB is huge and DOM approach is a pure memory overhead.

If any one can give me a sample in C#, I can implement it according to my requirement and it would be of great help.

Thanks a ton in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of useful Excel libraries that allow you to interact using managed .NET code (E.G., [Excel Helper Library](http://ehl.codeplex.com/) and [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)) with the "ExcelPackage" library appearing the most useful based on your question.

Looking at the sample provided in the [Excel Helper Library](http://ehl.codeplex.com/) it would appear working with Excel data is fairly straight forward ...

```
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(1, 1, "test1,1"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(1, 2, "test1,2"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(2, 2, "test2,2"));
excel.Add(new ExcelCell(2, 3, "test2,3"));
```

Without further information it will be difficult to help, so please provide more information on the problem you are facing if you need more assistance.

Comment: Hi Kane, Thanks for the information. I am not allowed to create a new cell or a row. All i have to do is insert the data into respective cell. For example, I have articles like Soaps, Chocolates, etc., items. These items will be retrieved from the database and will be populated in the 1st column, starting from the 2nd row. I some how figured out on how to do this. But the problem is that i have to retain the style. The template is buying plan template and has forecasting for each article. and the remaining columns will be the sub-categories of the main articles.

Comment: Continued.. The biggest problem is all the sub categories are dynamic. there are chances that there might not be any sub-category for an article. And I have to retain the style for each and every row and cell. Plz let me know if you need any further information. and I am allowed to use Open XML Reader and Writer only